# Creating a More Efficient Detection Method (jQuery, PHP, Web Application)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have this detection engine running in an inc.php file that is using jQuery detection on an input field and running a regex against what the user types:

```
    ..
    $trigger_selector = "[name^=trigger-]";
    ?>

    $("<?php echo $trigger_selector; ?>").on("change keyup paste blur", function() {
        run_macro_detector($(this));
    });

    function run_macro_detector(input) {
        var new_value = input.val();
        var input_id = input[0].id;
        var pattern = /(\$NAME\d+\$)/;
        var pattern_system = /(\$.*)/;

        test = pattern.exec(new_value);
        test_system = pattern_system.exec(new_value);

        if (test != null) {
            // add new_value to name_match_array
        }

        if (test_system != null) {
            // add new_value to macro_match_array
        }

        var match_array= name_match_array.concat(macro_match_array);
        input.autocomplete({ source: match_array });
    }
```

I'm thinking the regex is somewhat limiting on what I can do, but I would love to hear some suggestions on how to make this faster, less dependent on regex or if there is an easier way to do this.  I have also redacted a large bit of the code and mostly just trying to get the idea across.

Another problem that I had was how to get jQuery UI autocomplete to force detection on just the "$" character but not display it as an option in the dropdown.